# How many times has the Wilhelm scream been used in Star Wars films?

Tags: star-wars, wilhelm-scream

How many times in the Star Wars films (including SW stories) has the Wilhelm scream been used? I'm only asking about Episodes 1-8, Rogue One, and Solo.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ua2RWL5big

Comment: @ToddWilcox None excluded just not TV stuff, a Clone Wars, Rebels as too many to count.

Comment: @Valorum thanks for the clip, will watch it later. What's the count?

Comment: @Seamusthedog - Dunno. Didn't count 'em. You tell me.

Comment: @Valorum only seems to be 1 per film with nothing for TLJ, might have to watch them all back to back to be sure!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## In the 10 films you specified, there are 12 Wilhelm Screams.

[Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wilhelm_scream) gives us the following list:

***Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace***

- Naboo soldier shot in the Theed Hangar
- Another Naboo soldier 14 seconds later

***Star Wars: Episode II Attack of the Clones***

- Naboo guard falling from the ramp of the exploding J-type diplomatic barge on Coruscant,

***Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith***

- Knocked-back clone trooper on the Guarlara during the broadside battle with the Invisible Hand

***Star Wars: Episode IV A New Hope***

- Stormtrooper shot by Luke Skywalker prior to the chasm swing aboard the Death Star (this was the scream's debut in the Star Wars franchise)

***Star Wars: Episode V The Empire Strikes Back***

- Rebel soldier as a turret is destroyed by an All Terrain Armored Transport
- When Chewbacca throws a stormtrooper down right before Han Solo is put into carbonite

***Star Wars: Episode VI Return of the Jedi***

- Weequay falling into the sarlacc pit
- Another skiff guard falls into the sarlacc one minute later
- Colonel Dyer knocked off a catwalk by Han Solo in the Endor shield bunker
- Stormtrooper lifted by crowds on Coruscant

***Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens***

- First Order stormtrooper hit by an explosion aboard the Finalizer, as Finn and Poe Dameron attempt to escape in a TIE fighter

## There are an additional 6 Screams heard in Canon you did not ask about

***Star Wars: The Clone Wars (film)***

- At the monastery on Teth, after having recovered Rotta, a clone trooper is hit when an AT-TE cockpit explodes from the just-arrived Separatist Droid Army's fire

***Star Wars: The Clone Wars (show)***

- *S02E18 - The Zillo Beast*: Hawkeye is hit by the Zillo Beast's foot
- *S02E20 - Death Trap*: A couple of clone troopers are sent flying into space after the air vent opens
- *S03E13 - Monster*: In the ambient noise during Savage Opress's transformation)
- *S03E20 - Citadel Rescue*: During the space battle, a clone trooper aboard an exploding Republic vessel

***Star Wars Rebels Spark of Rebellion***

- A stormtrooper hit by Ezra Bridger's energy slingshot

---

Fun fact, Colonel Dryer in *Episode VI: Return of the Jedi* was portrayed by Ben Burtt (the man who found, and arguably popularized the Scream) and he mimicked the Wilhelm Scream himself on camera.